# Error deploying Django project on Railway

Tags: python, django, apache, railway

I'm trying to deploy a Django project on Railway and I'm getting a runtime error saying,

`"The 'apxs' command appears not to be installed or is not executable. Please check the list of prerequisites in the documentation for this package and install any missing Apache httpd server packages."`

As far as I'm aware I've installed Apache but have probably missed something.

---